# How to configure cmake for building shared library?

Tags: cmake

Im trying generate shared libs for GLFW in osx. When I set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS value on the Cmake GUI shows me this error:

```
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Using Cocoa for window creation
Using NSGL for context creation
Building GLFW only for the native architecture
Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) in src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "glfw" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which differs from
  its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework;/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework

  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:



This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warning not an error. It's a warning for the GLFW developers, not for you.